# Django storage s3 media url is https:// instead of http://

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

When serving media with django-storage s3, the media url that is being generated is something like this:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myimage.jpg?Signature=5ifoyLqzmtfVNS1ovfzVvN92RH0%3D&Expires=1363124819&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ7ZTU7K4SPYKGOFA
```

Causing the images to not be displayed because of https:

```
    You attempted to reach mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com,
 but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.s3.amazonaws.com.
 This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com.
```

**I need the images to be served as HTTP not HTTPS**

My settings are:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "AKIAJ....K4SPYKGOFA"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "2Y7G98JoCRzAEp....rPoCjWZuwDaQ"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "mybucket"
```

I tried set the media_url, and s3_url to normal http, but it didn't change anything.

I'm using django 1.5

Comment: Can you tell me where in the AWS console I would make that change?

Comment: You should make the change in the Django setting file (by default it's settings.py )

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm afraid I'm asking the wrong question. I just use S3 as a place to keep files that I download into my iOS app. I have previously used http but that is now failing, apparently Amazon changed to using https. My app is deployed and I'm trying to make AWS go back to responding to http. I don't think I am using django but this post seemed to be talking about the same thing. If you have anywhere to point me to figure this out I would appreciate it!

Comment: @AndrewSmith I see, sorry but I've no experience with this

Comment: Thanks for responding, turns out it was an Apple iOS issue!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would try adding this property to your settings:

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
```

It doesn't look like it's documented after a brief glance at the django-storages docs, but this blog talks about it a bit more.
http://www.eliotk.net/05/30/force-http-with-django-storages-and-s3boto/

Answer (score 9):

You could probably solve this with a single `AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False`. However these settings are in flux as of the current version **1.1.6** so here's a bit more detail on related settings:

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = 'http'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL is the *new* way and if set to an empty string allows protocol relative URLs. For backwards compatibility you still need AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS. And at the moment AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN is [necessary](http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/src/235946fdb10d2d8dbbc0f6ac2c5bb430dc86de0b/storages/backends/s3boto.py?at=default#cl-339) if you are using AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL. Here's some developer [discussion](http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/src/235946fdb10d2d8dbbc0f6ac2c5bb430dc86de0b/storages/backends/s3boto.py?at=default#cl-339) on implementing protocol relative URLs with the S3Boto backend.

It's also worth noting Django-storages provides an S3 backend as well as a different S3Boto backend. Your question doesn't make the one you are using clear though your code does.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer, and especially the last paragraph

Comment: AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL should be 'http:

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this issue with changing @JCotton answer line 2:

AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = 'http://'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35695345)