# Django + Amazon S3 not loading static files on production

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

So i have my Django site and i am trying to have my static files on S3, but i am getting a `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` when my site is on a production server. If i click on the link and accept it, it then loads the page.

I am using `django-storages` and on my local machine everything works fine (my S3 credentials are ok) but when i deploy to production i get the error.

Do i need to have https enabled on my site to be able to serve static files through S3??

What should i do?

THanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372041/django-storage-s3-media-url-is-https-instead-of-http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think my problem was related to bucket policies. i am not sure as i tried many different things but i would bet that's the one that made it work.

Comment: What did you had to do?

Comment: I wrote a blog post about it a few years ago. you can have a look here http://blog.nunokhan.com/2014/09/django-amazon-s3.html